# display image in a button and send hidden values in a form with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, image, button

I'm sorry for mi bad english, but I need to display an image in a button, then send hidden values in form post.

Mi code:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>";
echo '<input id="prueba" type="submit" value="Submit">​​​​';
echo "<input type='hidden' name='opt' value='3'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='sede' value='".$sede."'>";
echo '</form>';
```

In my CSS:

```
#prueba{
    background-image:url(back.png);
    font-size:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}​
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is wrong with this code? this should change background image of `prueba` submit button

Comment: whats the Problem? sending the form? to Display the Image in a button?

Comment: Try putting quotes for the image url: `background-image:url("back.png");`

Comment: Even if this is not relevant with your question, you might also want to consider using [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or cookies for storing and using data through different pages.

Comment: My problem is: the image is not display in the button and appear these characters "â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹". But the subtmit button is working fine.

Comment: After copy/pasting your code I saw some weird chars at the end of the `echo '<input id="prueba" type="submit" value="Submit">​​​​';`. Try deleting them and see if it works.

Comment: Do you use the UTF-8 meta-tag for the HTML-page? This should prevent charset falls ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply displaying an image and use javascript to click the submit button?

Example 1: *using "document.form.submit()'*

```
echo "<form id='myform1' method='post' action='index.php'>";
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" ';
echo   ' onclick="document.getElementById(\'myform1\').submit();">';
echo  '<img src="back.png" width="50" height="50" />';
echo '</a>';
echo "<input type='hidden' name='opt' value='3' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='sede' value='".$sede."' />";
echo '</form>';
```

or, Example 2: *use a hidden submit button (need jQuery)*

```
echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>";
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(\'#prueba\').trigger(\'click\');">';
echo  '<img src="back.png" width="50" height="50" />';
echo '</a>';
echo '<input id="prueba" type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" />​​​​';
echo "<input type='hidden' name='opt' value='3' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='sede' value='".$sede."' />";
echo '</form>';
```

or, Example 3: *use CSS to display the image*

```
echo "<form id='myform1' method='post' action='index.php'>";
echo '<a id="prueba" href="javascript:void(0);" ';
echo   ' onclick="document.getElementById(\'myform1\').submit();" />';
echo "<input type='hidden' name='opt' value='3' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='sede' value='".$sede."' />";
echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of input type= submit use

```
  <input type="image" src="back.png" alt="Submit">
```

Comment: But this won't automatically submit the form. Nothing will happen on click. But you can add some jQuery there ;)

Comment: errr ,yes it will, according to the w3 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html) and w3schools, I quote type=image Defines an image as the submit button [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)